# n1ql couchbase, Check last element in array matches a condition

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I need to select the record where number value matching the last element in the numbers array in couch base n1ql query

Check last element in array matches a condition
{
name: String,
data: {
dates: Array,
numbers: Array
}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last element in an array using the array index -1 in N1QL. So in your case, you might want to do something like the following:

```
select b.* from `bucket` b where b.data.numbers[-1] > 100;
```

Comment: Small correction: select b.* from `bucket` b where b.data.numbers[-1:] > 100; seems to be correct. Anyways selecting as correct answer. :)